# Facebook share go:image is deduced even if it provided and not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Strange behaviour when I want to share something on Facebook :

First time I try to share it, I get this on the Facebook Graph debugger :

> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

But when I click on the "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" button I see that :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/917d5e_5710fb93efc14a4aa52e3fc766441fe9~mv2.png">
```

If I scrap again with the debugger, everything is working fine, my of:image tag is found and the image is displayed in the preview.

I tried with several images, and the size of my image is not the problem.

The Facebook developper is full of issues like that but nobody on the dev team seems to answer...is somebody here managed to find a solution to that ?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have an example of a URL that you have problem with?

Comment: Yes you can try with this one : http://www.girafworld.com/Instants the first try will won't work, if it does, it means that this user had already share his profile I'll give you another URL. Thanks